# how can i prevent onbeforeunload from firing when a certain condition is met?

Tags: javascript

i have a page on which i want to confirm if the user wants to leave.
i have to confirm only when a certain condition is met so i wrote code like this

```
var back=false;
back=//check if user pressed back button
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    alert(back);   //this alerts true
    if(back==true)
        return false;
        //e.preventDefault;   --this does not work too
};
```

but this does not work. i mean when i click on back button this onbeforeunload still fires and i still get the confirmation message even when i m returning false.Whats can be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Return a string if you want to offer an option to the user to abort the unload. Return nothing in other cases.

```
var back = false;
back = true; //Somewhere, the condition is set to true
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if(back == true)
        return "Are you sure to exit?";
}
```

Comment: No you can't change the confirmation message, haha (joking)

Comment: @lovesh Browsers have their own implementations of the 'onbeforeunload' confirmation dialog with standard text that will always show, and not all of them will even display the text you've returned to the user.

Comment: @lovesh `return false` in your code **did work**. You've forgotten to set `back=true`.

Comment: @RobW i did. intentionally left that `back=` empty, thats why i said `alert(back)` shows true

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness here a more ***modern***, recommended approach:

```
let warn = false;
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', e => {
  if (!warn) return;
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
warn = true;  // during runtime you change warn to true
```

> Typically, it is better to use `window.addEventListener()` and the
>   `beforeunload` event, instead of `onbeforeunload`.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Syntax)

The reason why your originally posted code didn't work is that `false` is a non-null value. If you would have returned `null` or `undefined` in the situation where you don't want to spawn a pop-up warning your code would have worked as expected.

The currently accepted answer works because JavaScript implicitly returns `undefined` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function() {
    return "'Are you sure you want to leave the page. All data will be lost!";
});

$('#a_exit').live('click',function() {
    $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
```

Try this. Above code is working in most of conditions.

Comment: This doesn't address "when a certain condition" is met, this will always fire

Answer (score 1):

Condition for back-end

```
var confirmExist = function (e) {
    return true;
}
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExist;
http get, post request
.then(function(r)) {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider not setting the window.beforeunload event untill your list of conditions are met.

```
var confirmUserToLeave = function () {
    if (/* conditions are met */) {
        window.unbeforeunload = function (e) {
            /* whatever you want to do here */
        };
    } else {
        window.unbeforeunload = undefined;
    }
};
```

Then just call that method on certain events that might change the outcome of your 'conditions are met'.